# only inserting specific data in foreach ajax post

Tags: php

I currently have a form which then uses javascript / ajax to post the information into a function which then inserts the data into my database.

at the moment its inserting everything that is passsed via form.serialise, where as i'd like it to ignore params oppid & coverletter as they are inserted into a seperate table via a different code.

My php for insert is as follows...

```
    $insert1 = [];

    foreach ($this->input->post() as $k => $v) {

            $insert1['question_id'] = $k;
            $insert1['answer'] = $this->input->post($k, true);

            $this->db->insert("applicationquestionanswers", $insert1);

        }
```

My form gets posted via this javascript

```
$.ajax({ url: "https://XXXXX.com/apicalls/submitapplication",
                        method: "POST",
data: $("#applyform").serialize(),
                            success: function(data) {
                  $( "#applybtn" ).hide();
                $( "#applybtn1" ).show();
```

and at the moment these are the values getting passed through

oppid:
coverletter:
1:
2:

the form has fields with custom questions and the names of those text fields are the unique id for that questions i.e "1" is the id of the question from the database. ($k)

Hope this makes sense,

so basically, i want to ignore the params coverletter and oppid, (fields also on my form) as my code at the moment inserts everything into my table.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it, one being to get a list of the post variables and just unset the ones you don't want to use...

```
$insert1 = [];
$fields = $this->input->post();
// Remove fields not interested in saving
unset ($fields["oppid"]);
unset ($fields["coverletter"]);

foreach ($fields as $k => $v) {
    $insert1['question_id'] = $k;
    $insert1['answer'] = $this->input->post($k, true);

    $this->db->insert("applicationquestionanswers", $insert1);
}
```